# What's the difference of app.module.browser.ts vs app.module.shared.ts

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am working with ASP.Net Core 2.0 with Angular 4.0. Here i got confusion with **ClientApp -> app**  section. I need to know ***app.module.browser.ts*** and ***app.module.shared.ts***. I have searched many of the angular sites and docs, but i didn't get a proper solution in it.

Which section we need to add component to render in the browser.

[image: ASP Core 2.0 with Angular 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Microsoft SPA](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)** broke has up the app.module.ts into a client and server file to help with AOT rendering.

The **app.module.shared.ts** file is actually just a global file which has constants and can be consumed in app.module.client.ts and app.module.server.ts.

Comment: Bu we need to render components in app.module.shared.ts only?